# Conditional probability with infected bats

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Assume 20% of a bat population is infected by a certain disease.
Bats are classified as infected or non-infected by a particular test which
is not completely reliable. Assume the probability to classify a bat as
non-infected if it is infected is 0.10. Assume the probability to classify
a bat as infected if it is non-infected is 0.05. Determine the probability
that a bat is infected if it is classified as non-infected.

What I've done:

I = infected,
C = classified as infected

$$
P(I|\overline C) =\frac {P(I \bigcap\overline C)}{P(\overline C)} = \frac{.2 * .1}{.1} = .2
$$

I know the correct answer is 0.0256. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $P(I\cap \overline{C}) \neq P(I) \cdot P(\overline{C})$ in general scenarios.  This is only true if the probabilities are independent, which they are definitely not in this case.  You need to approach this using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayes' theorem gives
$$
P(I|\overline{C})={P(\overline{C}|I)\times P(I)\over P(\overline{C})}
$$
$$
P(\overline{C}|I)\times P(I)=0.1\times0.2
$$

$$
P(\overline{C}) = P(\overline{C}|I)\times P(I) + P(\overline{C}|\overline{I})\times P(\overline{I})
$$
$$
=0.1\times0.2+ 0.95\times0.8
$$

$$
P(I|\overline{C}) = 0.1\times0.2/(0.1\times0.2+0.95\times0.8)=0.0256.
$$